# HMS toolkit cloud debug device not showing in the selected device list in android studio

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Developer is able to open the HMS devices from cloud debugging, but device not showing in the selected device list in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the some supported environment:
[image]

If the issue is still there, then send feedback from the IDE where you are getting this issue.

[image]

HMS Toolkit team will track this issue from their end and get the root cause so that they can solve this issue asap